# разложение числа на слагаемые различными способами

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, рекурсия, комбинаторика

Вводится число, его нужно представить в виде суммы натуральных чисел различными способами(то есть, 1+2 и 2+1 - это один и тот же способ разложения числа 3). У меня при вводе 3 выходит 1. В чем ошибка?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int func(int val, int &c) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= val; i++) {
        
        if (val - i == 0) { return c+1; }
        else { return func(val - i, c); }
        
    }
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    int val = 0, c = 0;
    cin >> val;
    cout << func(val, c);
}
```

Comment: `func` умеет возвращать `0` или `0 + 1`. Результаты нигде не суммируются, переменная `c` никогда не меняется. Кстати, зачем вы передаёте её ссылкой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите рекурсивно, то, если не ошибаюсь, можно [так](https://ideone.com/kP7P2o)

```
int f(int val, int m = 1)
{
    if (val == m) return 1;
    if (val < m) return 0;
    int count = 1;
    for(int i = m; i <= val; ++i)
    {
        count += f(val-i,i);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Конечно, имеет смысл применить хотя бы мемоизацию, потому что для больших чисел будет считать издевательски долго :)

P.S. Тырить аватары некрасиво...

Comment: Так вас ответ устроил или вы вопрос задали только чтоб аватарку обсудить?

Comment: Устроил, спасибо

Comment: Тогда его имеет смысл принять? Спасибо здесь — треугольник вверх слева от ответа, большое спасибо — птичка там же...